# Why is this group a Lie group?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups

I'm reading an article in which the author proves a Theorem about topological groups (this is not an important theorem and it appears in the Appendix, however I would still like to understand it). The author claim (without proving) the following

> Let $G_1,...,G_5$ be five compact abelian groups such that $G_1/G_2$ is finite, $G_2/G_3$ is a torus, $G_3/G_4$ is either finite or the circle group and $G_4/G_5$ is finite then $G_1/G_5$ is a Lie group.

Any Ideas why this is true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you can replace all of your groups by $H_i=G_i/G_5$.

By [Hilbert's fifth problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_fifth_problem) a locally compact topological manifold group is necessarily a Lie group (a finite extension or an extension by a circle certainly gives a topological group). The abelian case was solved considerably earlier; see there.

Comment: This is not true. For instance $\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}\{1,-1\}$ is a compact group which is not a Lie group. Hilbert's fifth problem is about groups which are topological manifolds.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, thanks. Certainly a circle extension of a torus is a topological manifold :-)

Comment: No, this is not what Hilbert 5th says (think of p-adic numbers). One way to state it correctly is to require that the group contains no small subgroups .

Comment: @MoisheCohen, $p$-adics won't give you a topological manifold?

Comment: Oh, never mind, I did not notice that you said "manifold" (which makes "locally compact" unnecessary).

Comment: @MoisheCohen, I added "manifold" after Jose pointed out that my original formulation was incorrect.

Comment: Ok now I understand. I'll search online and check why a finite extension of a Lie group is a Lie group.

Comment: @yanko, it is right once the required condition of "topological manifold" has been clarified.  A finite extension of a Lie group is always a Lie group since the smooth manifold structure on each connected component is naturally induced by the one on the connected component of the identity element.

Comment: You may be interested in [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2335859/72694).